# Will the Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm always return the same min-cut for any source-sink from one side of the min-cut to the other?

Tags: network-flow, minimum-cuts, ford-fulkerson

I was playing around with https://visualgo.net/en/maxflow when I realized a pattern:

[image]

Take this graph, for example. We notice that the min-cut divides the graph into two sets of nodes: {0, 2, 3, 6} and {1, 4, 5, 7}.

I noticed that choosing any node within {0, 2, 3, 6} as a source and {1, 4, 5, 7} as a sink, or vice versa, produces the same min-cut edges.

Is this true in general? As in, will the min-cut produced be the same for any source-sink pair from one-side of a min cut to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an interesting observation.

However, the propostion is not true in general. For a counterexample, consider the flow network with capacities $c(\overrightarrow{AB})=2$, $c(\overrightarrow{BC})=1$ and $c(\overrightarrow{AC})=1$.

[image: a simple flow network made with https://graphonline.ru/]

Let $A$ be the source and $C$ be the sink. The unique min-$A$-$C$-cut is $(\{A,B\}, \{C\})$.

Let $B$ be the source and $C$ be the sink. The unique min-$B$-$C$-cut is $(\{B\}, \{A,C\})$.